# RequestPermissions isn't giving a prompt Android Studio API 32

Tags: java, android, request, sdk, chipmunk

I'm working on Android Studio chipmunk using java language.
I'm trying to request permission for Nearby devices. So far I have already tried the AppCompat and regular requestpermissions method but none seems to work.
The app is not prompting the user to allow the device to access any of the required permissions including Bluetooth, location, and nearby devices.

I am using Pixel 3 device to run my code with Android 12.

```
public void getpermissions(){
     
            if ((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) || (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) || (
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) !=
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) || (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ||
                    (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) !=
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) || (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ||
                    (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)||
                    (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) !=
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)||
                    (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION) !=
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)||
                    (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission_group.NEARBY_DEVICES) !=
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))  {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
                        , Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION,
                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission_group.NEARBY_DEVICES}, 1);
                //requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission_group.NEARBY_DEVICES}, 1);
                return;
            }
      
    }
```

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.navigation" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission-group.NEARBY_DEVICES" />
    "android.permission-group.NEARBY_DEVICES"

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Navigation"
        tools:targetApi="32" >
        <activity
            android:name=".DeviceScanActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I suggest you to use easy permission now its recomnded by alots of people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare a need for a background location when an app requests the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission or the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission.

```xml
<manifest ... >
  <!-- Always include this permission -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

  <!-- Include only if your app benefits from precise location access. -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: This answer looks like is was improperly [copied from the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#foreground).